# UV mapping based on distance from object origin

Tags: uv

The title says it all: I'd like to know if there's a less manual labor way to map the faces of an object based on their distance from center of the object, or perhaps 3D cursor.  I used to use this feature frequently on max, and it's quite useful when working with colorstrip workflows, where you have the base layer uv's as the color strip texture.

I'd like to use the gradients of my colorstrip texture to color the deeper regions of my object darker. I can do this manually by choosing every bump on my object, then map from view. This is rather tedious, though, and I thought there must be an easier way to do this.  It is also not perfect, because the handmade islands are harder to get to match up.

Is it possible to script one's own projection algorithms, maybe? Or maybe someone knows of a plugin, that already exists?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Distance from origin or cursor is 1D.  UV is 2D.  How do you want to map one to the other?  Just U = distance, V = 0?  Pics of wireframe->desired UV would help to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. Your title mentions UVs but it sounds like you may just be looking for a mask based on distance from object origin to feed through your color palette? In that case you could just use a spherical gradient with object coordinates. It does exactly that.

[image]

[image]